# with nginx, how do you rewrite a request to a different directory?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

on site, `favicon.ico` is kept in the `/images/` directory, not the root.  how do I tell `nginx` to look there?

have tried - which looks right but does not work:

```
location = /favicon.ico$ { rewrite /(.*) /images/$1 last; }
```

returns `404 Not Found`

the file is there: requesting `http://www.example.com/images/favicon.ico` is successful

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
location = /favicon.ico {
    root /path/to/your/images;
}
```

- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html
- http://nginx.org/r/location
- http://nginx.org/r/root
- http://nginx.org/r/alias
- http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls

Comment: works!  cool!  is there a way to do it using path relative do the _document_ root?  btw, great links

Comment: You can use the path relative to the server root, that was set at compilation time by the "prefix=" parameter, or by "p=" command line parameter, or by %%PREFIX%% env variable.
http://nginx.org/en/docs/install.html

Comment: But I recommend to stay with absolute paths. The explicit configurations is better than any implicit things.

Answer (score 2):

We can also solve this with rewrite. (I had to solve it using rewrite, because I'm using a `try_files` directive.)

Here's my config:

```
# Long cache times for static content
location ~ /_/static/(.+)$  {
    # hold the last five versions of our static content
    try_files
        /_/static_477526f-master/$1
        /_/static_05c8613-release/$1
        /_/static_05c8613-master/$1
        /_/static_db26497-release/$1
        /_/static_db26497-master/$1;
    expires  365d;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}

location = /favicon.ico {
    rewrite . /_/static/favicon.ico;
    expires  14d;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
}
```

The `.` regex matches anything, and the second entry rewrites the url. Since this is a favicon-specific location, we can just hardcode it instead of using regex capturing and `$1`.